# What happened to "Suggested Times" in Outlook (365) windows app?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

Suggested Times feature is missing as of a recent update in the Outlook -> New Meeting section - this was usually on the right side of 'room finder'
I have found these two recent articles I found but nothing else;
https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/mn6w7u/suggested_times_pane_missing/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/suggested-times-pane/941357f6-b276-4ce4-8f00-83bacc797d2d

No good replies.
There is nothing else I can find regarding this.
they DID add this feature to IOS, Android and webapp but removed it from the Outlook 365 desktop app??

Comment: [Microsoft's response seems pretty cut and dry.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/suggested-times-pane/941357f6-b276-4ce4-8f00-83bacc797d2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is the current design for the feature. We can view availability for people and rooms by clicking **Scheduling Assistant** on the ribbon and then click **AutoPick**.
[image]

[New Room Finder in Outlook](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/how-to-configure-the-new-room-finder-in-outlook/ba-p/1394162)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: It was yes.  I was hoping to find an article about the removal of the 'Suggested Times" feature so I can show the users I support an official link as to why they can't see this feature anymore.

Answer (score 1):

From the Start menu, type regedit.exe in the search box, and then press Enter.
If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

In Registry Editor, navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Calendar

Right click on Calendar and select New DWord (32-bit) value.

Set the Name to ShowLegacyRoomFinder and press Enter.

Right click the new key, select Modify and set the Value data to 1.

Close Registry Editor and restart Outlook.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-revert-the-outlook-desktop-webview-based-room-finder-to-the-legacy-room-finder-e872b6f2-0d36-41ff-861d-adaab2da9c28?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US